# C++ iterate through a template Map

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, iterator

When I have a template class which contains template map and a `const_iterator` declared as in the following code by `typedef`, how can I iterate through the elements of the map outside the class, f.e in main to print them on the output?

```
template<class K, class V>
class template_map{
private:

    typedef typename std::map<K,V> TMap;
    TMap my_map;

public:
    typedef typename TMap::const_iterator const_iterator;
    ...
};

int main()
{

template_Map<int,double> Map1 //suppose that contains elements

?
}
```

**Update:** Can the typedef iterator be used outside the class? If yes in what way?

Comment: Your main function is wrong. The complete type would be, for example, `template_map<int,double>`. Then you can just say `template_map<int,double>::const_iterator` to name your iterator. You also have to expose the iterator functions of `my_map` in the public interface of `template_map<K,V>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define member functions on your template that would return iterators:

```
template<class K, class V>
class template_map{

private:

typedef typename std::map<K,V> TMap;
TMap my_map;

public:
    typedef typename TMap::const_iterator const_iterator;
    const_iterator begin() const { return my_map.begin(); }
    const_iterator end() const   { return my_map.end(); }
};
```

Then:

```
int main()
{
    template_map<int, int> m;
    // Populate map...

    // Then iterate...
    for (auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++)
    {
    }
}
```

However, I am unsure what your adding to `std::map` here, why not just use it as is?

Answer (score 1):

Add begin() and end() members to template_Map (both const and non-const variants).

```
const_iterator begin() const {
    return my_map.begin();
}
const_iterator end() const {
    return my_map.end();
}
iterator begin() {
    return my_map.begin();
}
iterator end() {
    return my_map.end();
}
```

I added non-const versions just for interface completeness, it may not be required in your case.
Than in main:

```
typedef template_Map<x, y> template_MapXY;
template_MapXY Map1;
...
for ( template_MapXY::const_iterator it( Map1.begin() ), end( Map1.end() ); it != end; ++ it ) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to wrap a `map` class with another one. Why don't you `std::map` itself?

Iteration over a `std::map` is usually done like this:

```
for(std::map<mykey, myvalue>::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
{
    somevar = it->first; // <<--- points to your key
    someothervar = it->second; // points to your value
}
```

Comment: It is required to do that, it is not my choice.