# Strange behavior of upper_bound() in Maps

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I wrote a below sample code to understand upper_bound() in Map, however I could not understand the behavior for the below:-

```
// Sample upper_bound()
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <limits>

int main ()
{
  std::map<unsigned int,int> mymap;
  std::map<unsigned int,int>::iterator itup;

  mymap[0] = 5;
  mymap[5] = 5;
  mymap[10] = 5;
  mymap[15] = 5;
  mymap[20] = 5;
  mymap[25] = 5;
  mymap[30] = 5;

  // print content:
  for (std::map<unsigned int,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';


  itup=mymap.upper_bound (30);


  std::cout<<"First "<< itup->first<<": Second "<< itup->second<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound,

> "Iterator pointing to the first element that is greater than key. If
>   no such element is found, past-the-end (see end()) iterator is
>   returned."

Why does the past-the-end iterator return such values?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no key strictly greater than `30`, `itup` is the end iterator. You are not allowed to dereference the end iterator, so your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to understand your answer in another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415718/c-function-to-insert-to-template-map. 
Is it possible for me contact you elsewhere, in I do not have chat option here in SO?

Answer (score 1):

The following line:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (mymap.upper_bound(30) == mymap.end()) << std::endl;
```

indeed verifies that this is the iterator to `end`. You are not supposed to dereference this iterator. If you do - all bets are off, and you'll get some result that is unspecified.